# How to jest.spyOn a function without importing the entire module?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

In the past when I wanted to spy on a function in a module, I would do something like this:

```js
import * as myModule from 'my-module'
// ...
const mockMyFunction = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'myFunction')
// ...
mockMyFunction.mockReturnValue(123)
```

The problem now is I have hundreds of test files with this pattern and my tests are taking forever because I'm importing the entire module for 1 function.

How can I spy on or mock just that one function from that module without importing the whole thing?

Comment: Does `import { myFunction } from 'my-module'` work? It might still import the entire module but I'm not sure what toolchain you have - it might also tree-shake and only supply you with the one function.

Comment: But presumably the things you're _testing_ are also importing that module, so how can you avoid it?

Comment: @VLAZ It works in the sense that I can import it, but I can't pass the function itself to jest.spyOn, I have to pass the module itself and then refer to the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes the things I'm testing are also importing that module, but not with an `import *` statement. They're just importing the functions they need and nothing else.

Comment: Sounds you are ready for a structural solution, like splitting the module or concatenating test files